# Не устанавливаются библиотеки из терминала

Tags: python, консоль

Запускаю терминал, пытаюсь установить библиотеку, она устанавливается, но когда хочу ее подключить,Python ее не видит. А когда запускаю сам терминал, вижу такую ошибку:
Невозможно загрузить файл С:\User...  так как выполнение сценариев отключено в этой системе

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: может, при загрузке библы cmd от имени админа запустить?